# express-session: Why is redirect executed before my session info is set?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, express-session

Yet another "I've just started learning node.js/express and now I stuck" person here. I've tried looking everywhere for answers but I've reached a dead end. This is my first Stackoverflow question, so please tell me if I have done something wrong or unconventional.

I'm trying to create a POST request that saves a User-object to an express-session (on MongoDB), and redirects you to a URL that handles your session information.

The problem is, that the user is redirected before the header is set, and I am given the following:
`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Here is my code. I know it's a lot.. Im sorry.

#### router.post()

```
// Handler for POST requests from root page (/)
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Router: A POST request for: \"/\" has been called!");

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // Connect to database
    mongoose.connect(dbAddress);
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    // Report if error in connection
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Database: Connection error..'));

    // Callback function on 'open'
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log("Database: Connection successful!");
        console.log("Database: User supplied username: " + username);
        console.log("Database: User supplied password: " + password);

        // Find User object with a userId of req's username
        User.findOne({ 'userId' : username.toUpperCase() }, function(err, userObj) {

            if (err)
                return console.err(err);

            // Disconnect when done retrieving user object
            mongoose.disconnect();

            if ( userObj ) {
                console.log("Database: Returned password from MongoDB:");
                console.log(userObj.password);

                var db_password = userObj.password;

                if (password === db_password) {
                    console.log("Database: User Authenticated");

                    // Set 'req.session.user' as cookie
                    req.session.user = userObj;

                    // Redirect to homepage, with new cookie set
                    res.redirect('/');

                } else { // If passwords don't match
                    res.render('index', {
                        showError: true
                    });
                }
            } else { // If userObj is null
                res.render('index', {
                    showError: true
                });
            }

        });
    }); 
});
```

Note the 'req.session.user = userObj' part. Here I am trying to set 'user' in the session to the user object retrieved from MongoDB. In the next line, I am redirecting the user back to the GET request handler for '/' which handles the user based on the session information.

For some reason, these aren't happening in order. The GET request handler doesn't find req.session.user.

I understand that node.js is all about asynchronisation, but from other examples I've found online, this is supposed to work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9):

You could put your redirect inside a callback after the session is saved e.g:

```
...

// Set 'req.session.user' as cookie
req.session.user = userObj;
req.session.save(function(err) {
  // session saved
  res.redirect('/')
})

...
```

Hopefully this will make sure that the user is only redirected after the session is saved.

*Note: Make sure you hash your password with something like [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or pbkdf2*.